# Wrap text in tables in rubber columns

Tags: tables, columns

I can use `p{}`, `m{}` or `r{}` but I shall pass a fixed size. Is there a way to do it with rubber columns?

Comment: when you say 'rubber columns', do you mean columns with variable width? If so, have you seen the `tabularx` package?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to `tabularx` which sometimes works better (and sometimes doesn't) is to use `tabulary`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,tabulary}
\def\a{ one two three four five six seven eight nine}
\def\b{\a. \a. }
\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\noindent\begin{tabularx}
                {\textwidth} % table width
                {| l | X | X|} % X is for rubber column
     abc&1 1 1 \b\b&2\b\\
     def ge&22\b \b\b&red green blue
  \end{tabularx}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\bigskip

\noindent X\dotfill X


\noindent\begin{tabulary}
                {\textwidth} % table width
                {| l | L | L|} % X is for rubber column
     abc&1 1 1 \b\b&2\b\\
     def ge&22\b \b\b&red green blue
  \end{tabulary}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

TX and TY distribute the width between the columns in different ways. TY takes account of the content of the cells and tries to make columns with more content wider than those with less content. TX does not look at the content of the X columns.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use `tabularx` package.

```
% preamble
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabularx}
                {\textwidth} % table width
                {| l | X |} % X is for rubber column

            % your rows
            \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```